# How to show the Add-Ins manager dialog box?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Office 365 / Win7

I want my novice users to quickly view the PowerPoint Add-Ins manager dialog box without digging for it. (They won't have the Developer tab.)

In an add-in they have running that I wrote, I'm trying to code a button within a userform or as a menu command that opens the PowerPoint Add-Ins manager dialog box with a click (similar to xlDialogAddinManager in Excel).

If that can't be done, I'd like to code it to activate the Developer tab onto the tool ribbon if not already there, so the Add-Ins command can be accessed from there.

Comment: The command *should* be accessible from `Application.CommandBars`; find the `ID` for the command, then you can retrieve the command button object from the commandbar and `Execute` it.

Comment: GOT IT!! Works great! Thanks!! ... I turned from exploring CommandBars because I thought it was outdated and non-workable now, but I guess it can be used for such objects that otherwise can't be accessed?

For the record, I used...
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddInManager")

Comment: Huh, I tried to iterate the commandbars and their commandbuttons, and wasn't able to find the "add-ins" command button - feel free to post an answer documenting what the ID is for that particular command, could be helpful for others too!

Comment: Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddInManager")

Comment: I just corrected the code showing what I used. Thanks.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, feel free to post the answer in your name for credit and I'll delete mine. I just jumped the gun to put it out there for others. It was your idea, though, so please submit my code as the answer, then I'll delete my submission below.

Comment: @Mathieu, 
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "AddInManager"
that was the last code. Please submit it as an answer for credit. I've deleted my submission.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to delete it. LOL! I'm afraid I'll remove the entire thread. LOL.

Comment: No worries, you need the imaginary points more than I do! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Mathieu Guindon for the lead to use CommandBars, I came up with this and it worked for me...

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "AddInManager"
```

Comment: This is great! Do you know whether there is a list of all the objects that can be opened in this way? Also, do you know if the command is dependent on install language?

Answer (score 1):

Handy trick for locating the correct parameter for the .ExecuteMso command:

Go to the ribbon customization dialog. You may want to tell it to show all commands to make sure that .. well, that all the commands are showing.

Locate the one you're after, hover the cursor over it and the tool tip will show you what you need to invoke the button/whatever. It's the bit in parentheses at the end of the tooltip:

[image: Customize the ribbon to learn the correct parameter]

Comment: Steve, you rock! That sure beats sifting through the Office 2016 Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers files that I used to find the name!

Comment: And it's usually a nice/quick/easy way to test whether you've got the right gadget; add it to the ribbon, see if it's the one you want (lots of 'em have very similar names)